# Is it possible to assign same memory in function at different statement

Tags: c, gcc

Sorry for my bad english

Hi, today I got a memory problem.
or variable problem? I don't know.

this below is my source and it's simple

```
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errmsg.h>

typedef struct mysql_bind_list
{
    MYSQL_BIND *mysql_bind;
    unsigned int length;
} MYSQL_BIND_LIST;

MYSQL_BIND_LIST *create_mysql_bind_list()
{
    MYSQL_BIND_LIST mysql_bind_list;
    MYSQL_BIND_LIST *mysql_bind_list_point = &mysql_bind_list;
    mysql_bind_list_point->mysql_bind = (MYSQL_BIND *)malloc(1);
    mysql_bind_list_point->length = 0;
    printf("%p\n", mysql_bind_list_point);
    return mysql_bind_list_point;
}

void main()
{
    MYSQL_BIND_LIST *bind_list1 = create_mysql_bind_list();
    MYSQL_BIND_LIST *bind_list2 = create_mysql_bind_list();
}
```

And my gcc command is

```
gcc -o test.out test.c `mysql_config --cflags --libs` && ./test.out && rm test.out
```

I should explain point of that source, line of 18 that print memory address for mysql_bind_list_point using printf.
I hope to print different adress, but print same address like this.

```
$ gcc -o test.out test.c `mysql_config --cflags --libs` && ./test.out && rm test.out
0x7fff0851e2d0
0x7fff0851e2d0
```

How could it?
Somebody know this?

Comment: the function: create_mysql_bind_list() is returning the address of an item on the stack.  That results in undefined behaviour because when the function exits, the stack is no longer assured to be containing valid data.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable, and when the function returns that local variable goes out of scope leaving you with a stray pointer. Using that stray pointer leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you need to return a pointer to a structure, allocate the structure dynamically as well. And remember to `free` it once you're done with the structure.